# How to use json dictionary, so that is the key is blank then value will not select?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, dictionary

I am having the NSDictionary elements and this dictionary i am showing on the table, what i am doing that if any element is selected of these `dict` that will display on the textfield.

```
dict :{
    "" = "Select Elements";
    1 = lengha;
    2 = Choli;
    3 = Pyjami;
    4 = Dupatta;
    5 = Salwar;
    6 = Yoke;
    8 = Body;
}
```

Now i have to do with this that if the key is blank then value will not select on the textfield.i.e "Select Elements" this will not select on the textfield or if it is selected then data will not save and show some meassage on saving.

```
  UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [itemTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *elemCell = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
        NSMutableArray *arrayElements = Nil;
        if([elementsField.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            arrayElements = [NSMutableArray new];

        }
        else
        {
            arrayElements = [[elementsField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@","]mutableCopy];

        }
        if ([arrayElements containsObject: elemCell])
        {
            [arrayElements removeObject:elemCell];
        }
        else
        {
            [arrayElements addObject: elemCell];

        }
        NSString *str = [arrayElements componentsJoinedByString:@","];

        elementsField.text = @"";
        elementsField.text = str;
        [itemTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        itemTable.hidden = YES;

    }
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your actual question is, but I can tell you that making decisions based on the content of the cell is going to cause you problems when the table view scrolls and cells are reused; You should make decisions based on the content of your data model.

Comment: i want that "Select Elements" will not select

Comment: One way is in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you just deselect the row if it is the first/empty row

Answer (score 1):

That JSON data is misdefined and should look like:

```
choices : {
    "title" = "Select Elements",
    "elements" =  [
        "lengha",
        "Choli",
        "Pyjami",
        "Dupatta",
        "Salwar",
        "Yoke",
        "Body"
    ]
}
```

and that will solve your problem.